# C# 3.0 implicit cast error with class and interfaces with generic type

Tags: c#, oop, generics, casting

I implemented a few dependencies (which are the part of MVP pattern). Now, when I try to perform casting, VS informs about an error.

Definitions:

```
interface IView
{
     void setPresenter(IPresenter<IView> presenter);
}

interface IViewA : IView
{
}

interface IPresenter<T> where T : IView
{
    void setView(T view);
}

class PresenterA : IPresenter<IViewA>
{
}
```

Implicit cast:

```
IPresenter<IView> presenter = new PresenterA();
```

Compile error:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'PresenterA' to 'IPresenter'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Explicit cast:

```
IPresenter<IView> presenter = (IPresenter<IView>)new PresenterA();
```

Run-time error: InvalidCastException

How can I solve it to keep this conception? Conception with generic type (my previous one is without it). I've tried variance and contravariance issue (in and out) as mentioned in the others posts, but there was errors too (under VS 2010).

Comment: You can't, the constraint does not make sense.

Comment: Which constraint? The generic type included in IPresenter?

Comment: I went over it in detail with examples in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14779661/41655).

Answer (score 4):

The fact that `IViewA` derives from `IView` does not automatically mean that `IPresenter<IViewA>` derives from `IPresenter<IView>`. In fact `IPresenter<IViewA>` and `IPresenter<IView>` are two distinct types that do not have an inheritance relation between them. Their only common ancestor is `object`.

Let's look at an example. Assume that we have a class `Animal`, a class `Cat` deriving from `Animal` and a class `Dog` deriving from `Animal`. Now let's declare two lists

```
List<Animal> animals;
List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>();
```

And let's also assume that the following assignment was possible:

```
animals = cats;
animals.Add(new Cat()); // OK
animals.Add(new Dog()); // Ooops!
```

The list is in reality a cats list and we are trying to add a dog! Therefore the two types `List<Animal>` and `List<Cat>` are not allowed to be assignment compatible.

Answer (score 2):

This question is really about covariance and contravariance of generic types. We have

> an `IViewA` is an `IView`

but that does not automatically mean that

> an `IPresenter<IViewA>` is an `IPresenter<IView>`

*When* the conclusion holds, we say that `IPresenter<T>` is ***covariant*** in `T`. In C# one makes an interface covariant by putting an `out` keyword before the type parameter in question (here `T`), as in:

```
interface IPresenter<out T>  ...
```

Since you didn't put the `out` keyword, what you do is not allowed.

But it is only safe to make a type covariant in `T` if all the uses of `T` goes "out". For example it is okay to use `T` as return type of methods or as property type for `get`-only properties.

Your interface uses `T` in an "in" position, namely as a value parameter (i.e. a parameter without the `ref` (or `out`) modifier). So it would be illegal to make your interface covariant. See some of the other answers for examples of what could happen if this restriction wasn't there.

Then there's the notion of ***contravariance***, which for `IPresenter<>` means that

> an `IViewA` is an `IView`

implies that

> an `IPresenter<IView>` is an `IPresenter<IViewA>`

Notice how the order changes with contravariance. Contravariance is only safe (and only allowed) when the type parameter is used in "in" positions, such as value parameters.

Based on the only member, it would be legat to declare your interface contravariant:

```
interface IPresenter<in T>  ...
```

where `in` means contravariant, of course. But it will reverse the "direction" in which implicit conversions are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

By storing a `PresenterA` in an `IPresenter<IView>`, you're saying "this object has a method `setView` which accepts any `IView`".

However, `PresenterA`'s method `setView` only accepts an `IViewA`. If you passed it an `IViewSomethingElse`, what would you *expect* to happen?

It won't work, so the compiler doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do doesn't make sense. Imagine the following (including the one variance thingie that makes sense):

```
interface IView {}

interface IViewA : IView {}
class ViewA : IViewA {}

interface IViewB : IView {}
class ViewB : IViewB {}

interface IPresenter<in T> where T : IView
{
    void setView(T view);
}

class PresenterA : IPresenter<IViewA>
{
    public void setView(IViewA view) {}
}

class PresenterB : IPresenter<IViewB>
{
    public void setView(IViewA view) {}
}
```

Now, if the conversion you're trying to do were valid, you could do this:

```
IPresenter<IView> presenter = new PresenterA();
presenter.setView(new ViewB());
```

As you can see, this isn't typesafe. I.e. the relationship you believe exists between the types isn't there.

What variance lets you do is the opposite:

```
class Presenter : IPresenter<IView>
{
    public void setView(IView view) {}
}

IPresenter<IViewA> presenter = new Presenter();
```

`Presenter.setView()` can accept any `IView` parameter, therefore it can accept an `IViewB`. This is also why the compiler mentions an explicit conversion. It's to let you do the following:

```
IPresenter<IViewA> presenterA = new Presenter();
IPresenter<IView> presenter = (IPresenter<IView>) presenterA;
```

That is, to check if the value you're assigning to `presenter` at runtime happens to be one that's "generic enough", even if its compile-time type isn't.