# collection with in collection

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, c#-4.0, collections

I have a method in C#

```
private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, SimpleRule>>>> GetPSPFlags(long Id, string promo, int vs)
{
    const string qry = "select context, flag, name, rule " +
                       "from flags " +
                       "where id = :pId " +
                       "and code = :pc " +
                       "and vs = :v "

    var p = new OracleParameter[3];
    p[0] = new OracleParameter(":pId", Id);
    p[1] = new OracleParameter(":pc", promo);
    p[2] = new OracleParameter(":v", vs);
    string error;
    var results = Select(qry, p, out error);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error)) throw new ApplicationException(error);

    return results.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToDictionary(row => ToString(row["flag"]), row => SimpleRuleParser.GetRule(ToString(row["rule"])));
}
```

I am getting an error in the return type. How can I return a collection of context,flag, name and rule?

Comment: What is your error ?

Comment: What type does `SimpleRuleParser.GetRule` return?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `SimpleRuleParser.GetRule` returns a `Dictionary<string, SimpleRule>`.  If you want to return the rules as an enumeration of `KeyValuePairs`, then cast the values to that type

```
return results.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToDictionary(
    row => ToString(row["flag"]),
    row => (IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, SimpleRule>>)SimpleRuleParser.GetRule(
               ToString(row["rule"]))
           );
```

The error you get is because you cannot cast a

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, SimpleRule>>>
```

to a

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, SimpleRule>>>>
```

The cast I introduced for the parsed value has the effect that you get a

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, SimpleRule>>>
```

which implements the required method return type

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, SimpleRule>>>>
```

Your issue is about covariance and contravariance of generic types. See also my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779505/880990) to this question: [C# 3.0 implicit cast error with class and interfaces with generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779390/c-sharp-3-0-implicit-cast-error-with-class-and-interfaces-with-generic-type)

Note: The advantage of a `Dictionary<,>` is that it allows a very fast access of values by the key while an `IEnumerable<>` must always be enumerated to find a specific entry. So might actually be better to return the result through its original type `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, SimpleRule>>`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! How do I return something like this: collection[context,collection[flag]]

Comment: If you assign the result to a temp as `var temp = CreateTheCollection();` and then select `temp` in Visual Studio a light bulb appears. Click it and select `Use explicit type instead of 'var'`. VS will replace `var` by the explicit type. You can use it as return type.